# Using DSP instructions on arm cortex-M4 (C-language extension)

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I'm using CooCox CoIDE and GCC ARM embedded 4.9q2 and I use the cmsis library, programming on an ARM Cortex-M4 STM32F3 MCU.

I'm currently trying to do some quick saturating arithmetics inside an interrupt. I was under the impression that I could do that using the ARM C Language Extension (ACLE) to avoid having some assembler inserts in my C code.

However, when I call a function like __qadd16(a,b), I get an "undefined reference" error.

I suppose I have something more to include or a compiler option to specify in order to enable the ACLE, but I don't know which exactly.

So my questions are:

Is it possible or did I misunderstand the use of ACLE ??

What is the procedure to be able to call these functions? Are they not part of arm GCC? If not, what should I include?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

```
#include <core_cm4_simd.h>
```

From the CMSIS headers. It defines the instructions as inline functions, prefixed by `__`.

Comment: So I was indeed including <core_cm4_simd.h> but my problem came from elswhere.

Comment: So I was indeed including <core_cm4_simd.h> but my problem came from elswhere:
I was trying to call __qadd16(a,b) as defined in the ACLE doc which didn't work. Now I'm calling __QADD16(a,b) which works.
I'm not sure I really understand why, since core_cm4_simd.h simply uses #define __QADD16  __qadd16   so I assumed both should work and I was wrong.

Comment: You should look at the gcc part of that header. It supports various cimpilers (see the `#ifdef`s). Some provide the instructions as intrinsics (built-in). gcc requires assembler stubs.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I'm a first time user.